# Object oriented design - Shapes

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

So, after many years of OOP, I got a pretty simple homework assignment from one of my university courses to implement a simple object-oriented structure.

**The requested design:**

- Implement an objected oriented solution for creating the following shapes:
- Ellipse, Circle, Square, Rectangle, Triangle, Parallelogram.
- Each shape created must have the **following parameters** : unique id, color.

And following **functions**: color change, move, area, circumference, is inside, copy.

No validity tests are needed (not in the classes and not from user input).

**My design**:

[image]

Overall a pretty simple approach, shape_class / non-circular are abstract, and rectangle/square are combined into one class since they contain exactly the same parameters and no validity tests are needed (no reason to split them into two).

**Shape class** - implements a static id (unique id), and an init function dealing with the color name.

```
public abstract class shape_class {

    static int STATIC_ID;
    int id;
    String color_name;

    public shape_class(String color_name_input) {
        this.id = STATIC_ID;
        shape_class.STATIC_ID+=1;
        if (Arrays.asList(toycad_globals.ALLOWED_COLORS).contains(color_name_input))
        {
            this.color_name = color_name_input;
        }
    }

    public void change_color(String color_name_input) {
        if (Arrays.asList(toycad_globals.ALLOWED_COLORS).contains(color_name_input)) {
            this.color_name = color_name_input;
        }
    }

    public abstract shape_class return_copy();
    public abstract void move(double x, double y);
    public abstract double area();
    public abstract double circumference();
    public abstract boolean is_inside(double x, double y);
}
```

** Non-circular** - Receives an array of points (Which define the object) and implements almost all required functions.

```
public abstract class non_circullar extends shape_class {
    List<line> line_list = new ArrayList<line>();
    List<point> point_list = new ArrayList<point>();

    non_circullar(String color_name, point...input_point_list) {
        super(color_name);
        this.point_list = Arrays.asList(input_point_list);
        for (int current_index =0; current_index< (input_point_list.length); current_index++) {
            point current_first_point = input_point_list[current_index];
            point current_second_point = input_point_list[(current_index+1)%input_point_list.length];
            this.line_list.add(new line(current_first_point, current_second_point));
        }
    }

    public point[] get_point_list_copy() {
        int index = 0;
        point [] new_array = new point[this.point_list.size()];
        for (point current_point:this.point_list) {
            new_array[index] = current_point.return_copy();
            index+=1;
        }
        return new_array;
    }

    public double circumference() {
        double sum = 0;
        for (line current_line :this.line_list) {
            sum += current_line.get_length();
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public void move(double x, double y) {
        for (point current_point :this.point_list) {
            current_point.move(x, y);
        }
    }

    public boolean is_inside(double x, double y) {
        int i;
        int j;
        boolean result = false;
        for (i = 0, j = this.point_list.size() - 1; i < this.point_list.size(); j = i++) {
            if ((this.point_list.get(i).y > y) != (this.point_list.get(j).y > y) &&
                (x < (this.point_list.get(j).x - this.point_list.get(i).x) * (y - this.point_list.get(i).y) / 
                        (this.point_list.get(j).y-this.point_list.get(i).y) + this.point_list.get(i).x)) 
           {
              result = !result;
           }
        }
        return result;
    }

    int get_top_left_line_index() {
        int top_left_line_index = 0;
        int index = 0;
        point best_point = this.line_list.get(0).get_average_point();
        point current_point;
        for (line current_line :this.line_list) {
            current_point = current_line.get_average_point();

            if (current_point.x < best_point.x) {
                best_point = current_point;
                top_left_line_index = index;
            } else if (current_point.x == best_point.x && current_point.y > best_point.y) {
                best_point = current_point;
                top_left_line_index = index;
            }
            index +=1;
        }
        return top_left_line_index;
    }
}
```

**The problem:**

For this assignment 40 points were reduced for design issues:

1) Circle is an ellipse and thus needs to inherit from it (Even though they share no parameters).

2) Rectangle / Square are two different entities even though in this implementation they are exactly the same (no validity tests).

I would be happy to get some inputs from the community regarding this design, are the design issues 'legit' or not, and what could have been done better?

**Edit 1:**

An ellipse is expressed by : two points and d (For a point to be on the ellipse the distance between it and the two points must be equal to d).

A circle is expressed by : center and radius.

I find it very hard to understand how they can share common params.

Comment: What every square is a rectangle with same width and height.

Comment: I would have said that a `Circle` is an `Ellipse`, not vice-versa

Comment: Why do you need a `non-circular` class exactly, is there a reason you give more "importance" to circle and ellipse ? Also I believe `Ellipse` could be a subclass of `Circle` since this is a circle with two "center". And then every quadrilateral are linked together based on specif rules (a square is a specific rectangle), so you could create a better design. Creating an abstract class for circular, 3-side, 4-side, n-side... would probably be a better approch.

Comment: Nope nope. A circle is a particular Ellipse, a Square is a parallelogramm, you need to chang all^^

Comment: You dont need Non circular class i guess.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yea, I swapped that out by mistake, the question is do you always go for inheritance even when your specific implementation shares no common grounds?

Comment: @AxelH Hey, I added the non circular class implementaion, I think it would explain it, by breaking it into an extra layer I managed to implement almost all required functions (every non-circular shape is basically a group of lines).

Comment: @Javafan-Shashank- Look at my response to axel

Comment: Well, first you should rename that into `Polygon`. Then, you can regroup `Rectangle`, `Square` but also `Parallelogram` (and every `Quadrilateral`) in an abstract class that will insure that you only have 4 corner. Same logic for `Triangle` and other shapes. Using an abstract class to limit the number of corner. For the `area` and `circumference`. (It would be complicated to answer this question unfortunalty since I would need to draw the class diagram completely ;) )

Comment: @AxelH I guess I could do that, but the implementation of the area function would be quite complex. The renaming to polygon is a  really legit clam.

Comment: You still have subclass for each shape extending `Quadrilatral` (was not clear about that, sorry). The abstract class is just there to add a validation during the construction. (you don't want to check for each 4 side shape if you only have 4 point in the `point` varags. You do it once in `Quadrialeral`, same for `Triangle` checking you receive 3 point, ...

Comment: @AxelH But if no validation is required why would I want to split a square and a rectangle into two different classes, implementation wise they are exactly the same.

Comment: I only need to give you one reason "For future improvements" ! Not having to implements a validation layer doesn't mean it will never be needed. Future developer will thanks you later!

Comment: @AxelH I absolutely agree, but since this was an university assignment I really didn't bother. Please put everything you said into an answer, and Ill mark this as solved :)

Comment: See the top answer to [Can the circle-ellipse problem be solved by reversing the relationship](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/314646/can-the-circle-ellipse-problem-be-solved-by-reversing-the-relationship). See also [Alistair Cockburn's Constructive deconstruction of subtyping](https://web.archive.org/web/20160714194820/http://alistair.cockburn.us/Constructive+deconstruction+of+subtyping)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The design you have used is not idea (IMHO).

First, rename `non-circular` into `Polygon` (Also, us uppercase for the first letter).

Based on the implementation, a `Circle` is a specific `Ellipse` so I would have used inheritance here

```
Shape < -- Circular < -- Ellipse < -- Circle
      < -- Polygon < -- Triangle      < -- Equilateral
                                      < -- ... //don't know the english names of those triangles 
                   < -- Quadrilateral < -- Square
                                      < -- Rectangle
                                      < -- ...
                   < -- Hexagon
                   < -- ...
```

Each subclass of `Polygon` are abstract, those are used for the validation of the number of corners.

In general, I would have linked `Square` and `Rectangle` based on the geometry rule (same width and heigth) ( `Square extends Rectangle`) but based on your implementation using `Point` and `Line`, this is not required.
But using two classes would still allows some validation in the future ( every `Line` for a Square need to have the same length, ...).

*This shows that a design depends mostly on the requirement, not only on the subject.*

About `Ellipse` and `Circle`. An `Ellipse` is form of two points, if those point are the same, this is a `Circle`, this can be a link ;)

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you follow this scheme:

[image]

You need to categorize shapes by the number of the edges first and then by the common characteristics. Then you have to recognize the following facts:

- `circle` is just a special type of `ellipse`
- `square` is just a special type of `rectangle`
- both `rectangle` and `parallelogram` have 4 edges
- unlike`parallelogram`, `rectangle` have *all* the angles of 90°.

This is a simplified scheme according to your needs:

> Ellipse, Circle, Square, Rectangle, Triangle, Parallelogram

**Edit:** Note that there exists the following hierarchy as well. Both `rectangle` and `parallelogram` have the opposite edges of the same length. Finally, it depends on the preferred interpretation and on what suits your situation better (thanks to `@Federico klez Culloca`):

```
Quadrilateral <- Parallelogram <- Rectangle <- Square
```

**Make it scalable:** In case of more complex shapes of elementary geometry included, I'd put probably place `polygon` below `shape` and then differentiate the descendants by the convexity and non-convexity first.

Comment: Ok, but isn't a `Rectangle` a particular case of a `Parallelogram` with all the angles at 90°?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: Agreed. I divided `rectangle` and `parallelogram` based on the angles (both `rectangle` and `square` have them of 90°, `parallelogram` not). On the other hand, `rectangle` and `parallelogram` have both two sides of the same length (the perimeter of both is `2*(a+b)`) - yet another criterion of the division. I think your version seems more accurate.  However, the final choice is up to OP. I will edit my answer according to your hint. Thank you :)